# Using Nest to build continued fraction

Tags: functions, functional-style, iteration

To build basic continued fraction one can simply use:

```
Nest[1/(1 + #) &, x, 3]
```

[image]

---

> However, it's unclear how using `Nest` function one can generate
>   continued fraction of the following type:

[image]

---

I tried:

```
Nest[#/(1 + #) &, x, 3],
```

with the result:

[image]

Which is clearly not what I expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
Nest[x/(1 + #) &, x, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following.

```
f = Replace[#, 1/a_ -> x/a] &;

g[n_Integer] := Map[f, Nest[1/(1 + #) &, x, n], Infinity] // f;
```

Let us check

```
g[5]
```

[image]

```
g[10]
```

[image]

Have fun!